# The document root of my virtual host in wampserver is not changing to laravel's public folder. Can anyone explain it to me?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, http, laravel-5

The steps that I made are the following:

1. First, I added a servername on the hosts file on `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` folder.
   [My hosts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrTMc.png)
2. I made the following changes at `httpd-vhosts.conf`:
   [My httpd-vhosts.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVwIZ.png)
3. Lastly, I changed the documentroot path at `httpd.conf`.
   [My httpd.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo71t.png)

However, when I entered virtual virtual host name hxhking.com. The path is the same as the `c:\wamp64\www directory`.
This was shown: 
[hxhking.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG8fw.png)

Does anyone have an idea on what went wrong or what did I miss?

I need to change the path to my laravel application's public folder. 
I'm using an apache 2.4.23 and laravel 5.5...

Comment: Did you restart Apache? The configuration files are only parsed at startup, not on the fly.

Comment: @EdCottrell Yes, I did several times. I'm clueless. I also ran apache and notepad as administrator.

Comment: Restart and try it after changing the virtualhosts order as first hxhking.com.

Comment: @Daein I did that too... I placed the hxhking.com at a higher priority than localhost.. I think there might be something wrong with the installation of my apache...

Comment: I solved it guys worry no more...l should have written something like this ${INSTALL_DIR}/www/larablog/public... thank you for the reply...